# i can't run a lua game in love2D

Tags: lua, love2d

When I try to run the game, I receive this error:

```
Error

[love "boot.lua"]:323: Cannot load game at path 'C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/LUA-Projects- 
master/projects/3.Battle_arena.lua'.
Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'error'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Note: I'm running the lua file by dropping it on the love2D application window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to drag the directory containing a `main.lua` onto the love executable. In your case, rename `3.Battle_arena.lua` to `main.lua`, assuming your file is the entry point.

From [Getting Started](https://love2d.org/wiki/Getting_Started)

> LÖVE can load a game in two ways:
>
> - From a folder that contains a main.lua file.
> - From a .love file that has a main.lua file in the top-most directory level (aka root)

Answer (score 0):

do you have a `main.lua` in the game folder? love2d requires the game folder to have `main.lua` in order to run the game, rename `3.Battle_arena.lua` to `main.lua`.

if you have any other problems try visiting love2d.org